# Is it possible to have two different paths using breadcrumbs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm using MvcSiteMapProvider to generate breadcrumbs in my application.

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()
```

In the application we have a Batch entity and an Item Entity. Batches have items. But it's possible in the application to access Items without passing through a specific Batch.

I'd like to show path followed by the user if she has passed by Batch like this:

Home -> Batches -> [BatchNumber] -> [Item]

And if the item was accessed directly I'd like to show a path like this:

Home -> Items -> [Item]

My mvc.sitemap is configured as follows:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="$resources:Resources.Resources,Home" controller="Home" action="Index" preservedRouteParameters="culture">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="$resources:Resources.Resources,Batch" controller="Batch" action="Index" preservedRouteParameters="culture">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="$resources:Resources.Resources,NewBatch" controller="Batch" action="Create" preservedRouteParameters="culture" visibility="SiteMapPathHelper,!*" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Edit" controller="Batch" action="Edit" preservedRouteParameters="culture,batchId" visibility="SiteMapPathHelper,!*">
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Item" controller="Item" action="Edit" preservedRouteParameters="culture,itemId,batchId" visibility="SiteMapPathHelper,!*">
        </mvcSiteMapNode>
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="$resources:Resources.Resources,NewItem" controller="Item" action="Create" preservedRouteParameters="culture,noLot" visibility="SiteMapPathHelper,!*" />
      </mvcSiteMapNode>
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="$resources:Resources.Resources,Item" controller="Item" action="Index" preservedRouteParameters="culture">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Item" controller="Item" action="Edit" preservedRouteParameters="culture,itemId" visibility="SiteMapPathHelper,!*">
      </mvcSiteMapNode>
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="$resources:Resources.Resources,NewItem" controller="Item" action="Create" preservedRouteParameters="culture" visibility="SiteMapPathHelper,!*" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
```

Is it possible to do that?

With the current configuration the path shown is always:

Home -> Batches -> [BatchNumber] -> [Item]

If I invert the order inside the mvc.sitemap file it always shows:

Home -> Items -> [Item]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The first match always wins and multiple nodes that use the same route value configuration are ***not supported***.

The SiteMap does not use session state at all and therefore has no concept of a "previous URL" the user visited. See [How To Make MvcSiteMapProvider Remember a User's Position](http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position) for a complete explanation of how it works.

The only built-in option is to [add additional information to the URL](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Multiple-Navigation-Paths-to-a-Single-Page) (either the path or the query string) to differentiate the URLs, since the first match always wins. You could potentially generate a different URL when the user is on the "pass through" page.

However, it is also possible to use dependency injection to replace the matching behavior of `MvcSiteMapProvider` so it can match session state values. If you did it that way, then the URL wouldn't need to be different, but you would still need to set a session state key and value on each "pass through" page. As long as you consistently configure a default page when the user doesn't pass through any page it should work fine. See the [demo project](https://github.com/NightOwl888/MvcSiteMapProvider_383) and [explanation how to use it](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/383#issuecomment-74907681).